# Configure ESAPI Security Encoding Library to prevent XSS Cross-site scripting issue

Tags: java, security, xss, owasp, esapi

Am trying to use ESAPI for security encoding in a webapp (Jsps) to prevent XSS. I added esapi-2.1.0.jar under WEB-INF/lib and added below lines in JSP for encoding

```
ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML(request.getParameter(""))
```

But I get an exception as below

```
org.owasp.esapi.errors.ConfigurationException: ESAPI.properties could not be loaded by any means. Fail.
org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultSecurityConfiguration.loadConfiguration(DefaultSecurityConfiguration.java:439)
```

I understand the problem is missing ESAPI.properties file. Should I download this file as well along with esapi-2.1.0.jar? I could see ESAPI.properties is not in esapi-2.1.0.jar. Should I create my own or can I get a default file as am unsure what should be in it ? Appreciate any help.

Comment: If my answer worked for your question, please accept my answer by clicking the green check mark by it, and if you found it especially helpful, upvote it!  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most recent public configuration files are located [here](https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/tree/master/configuration/esapi):

If you read the comments/code in [this file](https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/blob/master/src/main/java/org/owasp/esapi/reference/DefaultSecurityConfiguration.java), you'll see how to handle file location.

You will need BOTH esapi.properties and validation.properties in order to properly use the library.

Here's an excerpt from the documentation.

```
/**
 * The reference {@code SecurityConfiguration} manages all the settings used by the ESAPI in a single place. In this reference
 * implementation, resources can be put in several locations, which are searched in the following order:
 * <p>
 * 1) Inside a directory set with a call to SecurityConfiguration.setResourceDirectory( "C:\temp\resources" ).
 * <p>
 * 2) Inside the System.getProperty( "org.owasp.esapi.resources" ) directory.
 * You can set this on the java command line as follows (for example):
 * <pre>
 *              java -Dorg.owasp.esapi.resources="C:\temp\resources"
 * </pre>
 * You may have to add this to the start-up script that starts your web server. For example, for Tomcat,
 * in the "catalina" script that starts Tomcat, you can set the JAVA_OPTS variable to the {@code -D} string above.
 * <p>
 * 3) Inside the {@code System.getProperty( "user.home" ) + "/.esapi"} directory (supported for backward compatibility) or
 * inside the {@code System.getProperty( "user.home" ) + "/esapi"} directory.
 * <p>
 * 4) The first ".esapi" or "esapi" directory on the classpath. (The former for backward compatibility.)
 * <p>
 * Once the Configuration is initialized with a resource directory, you can edit it to set things like master
 * keys and passwords, logging locations, error thresholds, and allowed file extensions.
 * <p>
 * WARNING: Do not forget to update ESAPI.properties to change the master key and other security critical settings.
 *
 * @author Jeff Williams (jeff.williams .at. aspectsecurity.com) <a href="http://www.aspectsecurity.com">Aspect Security</a>
 * @author Jim Manico (jim .at. manico.net) <a href="http://www.manico.net">Manico.net</a>
 * @author Kevin Wall (kevin.w.wall .at. gmail.com)
 */
```

Comment: Thanks you. By BOTH do you mean esapi.properties and validation.properties?

Comment: Yes, I mean both.  Fixed this!! thanks for the catch.

Comment: Thank You. Should I take esapi-java or esapi-java-legacy?

Comment: If you're using 2.x esapi-java-legacy.  The other is the stub branch for esapi 3.x.

Comment: Am using esapi-2.1.0.jar and taken prop files from esapi-java-legacy. Hopefully it works. Thanks for your help :-)